# Append byte after byte array

Tags: java

I have a byte array. But I want array length mod 4=0. So I want to add 00 after array until pass condition.
I find many solutions to append array

```
byte[] arr_combined = new byte[arr_1.length + arr_2.length];
System.arraycopy(arr_1, 0, arr_combined, 0, arr_1.length);
System.arraycopy(arr_2, 0, arr_combined, arr_1.length, arr_2.length);
```

But I do not want to create new byte array. I only want append byte after a byte array. Thanks

Comment: Arrays have a fixed length. if you want to append and change size, use a `List`

Comment: I would calculate the prefered length, use that result to create a new array, and fill in the data.

Comment: As Dragondraikk said, use a List, once you're done convert it to an Array. It will be much easier.

Answer (score 4):

As it was already mentioned, Java arrays have fixed size which cannot be changed after array is created. In your case it's probably ok to use `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
out.write(arr_1);
out.write(arr_2);
byte[] arr_combined = out.toByteArray();
```

This way you work with primitive `byte` type (unlike `List<Byte>`) which will be more efficient. The drawback is that `ByteArrayOutputStream` is synchronized, so there's some overhead for synchronization (though I guess it's much lower than boxing/unboxing overhead when using `List<Byte>`). Another drawback is that `ByteArrayOutputStream.write` is declared to throw `IOException`. In practice it's never thrown, but you have to catch/rethrow it.

If you don't mind using third-party libraries, there are plenty ways to create convenient wrappers over the primitive types which don't have these drawbacks. For example, [`TByteArrayList`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TByteArrayList.html) from Trove library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array you can't modify the length of it. You should use an ArrayList:

```
List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
```

Here you can add a new element wherever you want just using `add` method so, supposing that `b` it's a `byte` variable:

```
bytes.add(b);
```

So, in this way, you can add the number of 00 that you want regardless of the length of the `ArrayList`.

**EDIT:** I saw now on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340999/create-an-arraylist-of-bytes) that you can convert the `ArrayList` when you have complete it to an `array`, like this:

```
Byte[] arrayBytes = bytes.toArray(new Byte[bytes.size()]);
```

I expect it helps to you!

Comment: how can Byte[] be converted to byte[]?

Comment: @ArthurEirich if you have an array of byte[] called `newBytes` you can do this: `newBytes.toPrimitive(arrayBytes,//Here the value to set if it is null);`